# find the non constant polynomial so that P(x) δ_1' = δ_1'

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

This is the last one for today:

I am trying to find a non-constant polynomial $P(x)$ so that the following equation is true:

$$P(x) δ_1' = δ_1'$$

where $δ_1$ is the Dirac distribution supported in the point $x = 1$, and $δ_1′$
is the derivative of $δ_1$.

I started like this:

for a test function $φ$ we can write:

$$P(x)δ_1'(φ)=δ_1'(Pφ) $$

since $P(x)$ is a polynomial and then a function of class C^infinite, Right? if so then:

$$δ_1'(Pφ)=-δ_1(P'φ+Pφ')=-P'(1)φ(1)-P(1)φ(1)'$$

And now I don't know what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by  δ_1' ?

Comment: the derivative of the Dirac delta fuction supported in point x=1 =)

Comment: You almost got it in the last line. Now you want to set $\delta_1'(P\varphi) = \delta_1'(\varphi)$. This will give you conditions on $P$, and you just need to find one $P$ that satisfies them.

Comment: but I must get rid of the test function, how do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write, for each $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$, we must have 
\begin{align*}
  (P\delta_1')(\phi) &= \delta_1'(P\phi)\\ &= -\delta_1\bigl((P\phi)'\bigr)\\ &= -(P\phi)'(1)\\ &= -P'(1)\phi(1) - P(1)\phi'(1)\\
    &= -P'(1)\delta_1(\phi) + P(1)\delta_1'(\phi)
\end{align*}
This equals $\delta_1'(\phi)$ for all $\phi$ iff $-P'(1) = 0$ and $P(1) = 1$. Can you find a $P$ that satisfies this two conditions?

Comment: oh, yes I can=) thank you